# I want to show clock on vscode on my macbook touchbar using extension api

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I know basics of vscode extensions API. I have created my own extension [git-touchbar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MohammadDehgamwala.git-touchbar) for my personal use for some git commands. So coming to the point,What I want to show is  clock(hh:mm) on my touchbar extension. As far as i read docs, if i want to show some text on touchbar, i can do something like this...

```
 "contributes": {
"commands": [
  {
    "command": "git-touchbar.showTime",
    "title": "12:00"
  }}}
```

---

But it's static. What i want do is to update title property on touchbar after some interval like 1 minute. it doesn't have to update after each second . There is already some extensions available which shows clock on status bar. but i want to show it on my touchbar extension.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can add 24 (00-23) hour commands and 60 (00-59) minute commands to the menu and use the context variables `touchbar-hour` and `touchbar-minute` to control which command is visible.

```
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "git-touchbar.hour00",
        "title": "00:"
      },
      {
        "command": "git-touchbar.hour01",
        "title": "01:"
      },
.....
    ]
    "menus": {
      "touchBar": [
        {
          "command": "git-touchbar.hour00",
          "group": "gittools",
          "when": "touchbar-hour == 0"
        },
        {
          "command": "git-touchbar.hour01",
          "group": "gittools",
          "when": "touchbar-hour == 1"
        },
.....
      ]
    }
```

In your extension you set the value of the 2 context variables.

You should write a small Node or Python script to generate the 168 entries of `package.json`

Comment: Thanks for this answer. looking forward to implement this

Comment: @MohammadDehgamwala If this solves your question you can mark this answer as the solution